# How to set debugserver's log level to LOG_RNB_PROC?

Tags: ios, debugging, lldb

In LLVM project, debugserver.cpp has many logging levels.
How to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are usually using lldb to launch debugserver, it's most convenient to get it to turn on the logging.  There's an lldeb setting to send "extra startup commands" to debugserver that you can use to turn this on.  Something like:

```
settings set target.process.extra-startup-command QSetLogging:bitmask=LOG_PROCESS|LOG_EXCEPTIONS;
```

You can "|" together any of the log bits defined in debugserver.  That has to be set in lldb before you connect to debugserver (generally by doing `run` or `gdb-remote`.)